How to add translations to the in-store description of Chrome extension
I added translations for my short description and in app texts using i18n api of Chrome. I want to add translations to the red part of the image (https://i.sstatic.net/38b0wKlD.png). But how to add translations to the description we see in the Chrome web store?
I searched around the internet but nothing could help me fix my problem.

Do you want your extension's store page to be multilingual?

@NorioYamamoto Yes

Have you read this?
